# Hovering on buttons using jquery?

Tags: jquery, button, hover

Doing a hovering event on button as below.

```
<div id="common_id">
<div class="button" id="make_larger">
<button type="button">Large</button> 
</div>
<div class="button" id="make_small">
<button type="button">Smaller</button> 
</div>
<div class="button" id="make_normal">
<button type="button">Normal</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery code is:

```
 $('#common_id .button').hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover1');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover1');

        });
```

Css is:

```
.hover1 {

background-color:Black;
position:relative;

}
```

When placing mouse over buttons ,the complete row(From starting to end of page) is getting black even button is not getting black but its background is seems to be black along that row.
i want the button to be black when i hover on it.
Why it is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the css `:hover` pseudoselector? Use the CSS rule `#common_id .button:hover {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the div is taking the 100% width. so instead of selecting the div select the button. So your selector should look like this

```
$('#common_id .button button').hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover1');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover1');

        });​
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rekQ9/12/)

Comment: Great .
Thanks Sir.
                 .button is a div class.Can you please tell what does the second "button" label means?

Comment: the second button in the selector means . . . select all button tags. So the selector statement means that jQuery is looking for button tags contained within an element with a class of 'button' contained within an element with an id of 'common_id'.

Comment: the second button is just the element "<button../>" used there

Answer (score 2):

Remove the jQuery entirely and use:

```
#common_id .button:hover {
    background-color:Black;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sohhee's answer is right,but I think the CSS script you need should be

```
#common_id .button botton:hover {
   background-color:Black;
   position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the css only answer is the best - but you can select buttons on a page by using the jQuery selector $('button'), like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2fH7f/