# JavaScript/jQuery guidance needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Today I am building my self a vertical navigation menu and I'm wondering how I would go about build a particular feature I was thinking of.

Here is the coding behind my buttons:

**html:**

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">
    <img src="../images/article.png" />
    <p>Articles</p></a>
</div>

<div class="button"><a href="#">
    <img src="../images/leaderboards.png" />
    <p>Leaderboards</p></a>
</div>

<div class="button"><a href="#">
    <img src="../images/events.png" />
    <p>Events</p></a>
</div>

<div class="button"><a href="#">
    <img src="../images/search.png" />
    <p>Search</p></a>
</div>

<div class="button"><a href="#">
    <img src="../images/other.png" />
    <p>Other/Tools</p></a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.button{
    border-left:10px solid #e5dad6;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**My Goal:**

Now my goal is to change the image of the relevant buttons when a user hovers over the whole div (button div), now of course I can do this by adding a hover state in css, but that's not what I want to do, because I don't want to just change that particular div.

**What I want:**

I want it so I can basically say = if .button is being hovered over, then change the img src of something else on the page, NOT change something related to the element being hovered over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11863015/1686330

Comment: No because im trying to change an image on the page, not change classes.

Comment: Sure, but it's the same functionality as you can see in the answers of Dan or Tim Dinh. You can do what you want in a hover() handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oldSrc = $('.myNewImage').attr('src');

    $('.button').hover(function() {
        //on hover of your element

        $('.myNewImage').attr('src','http://mynewimagesrc.com');
    }, function() {
        //when the cursor leaves your element

        $('.myNewImage').attr('src', oldSrc);
    });
});
```

You'll have to switch out the .myNewImage, class for the actual class of the image on your page but that should work for what you're asking. It also assigned the original source of your image so that you can always return the element back to it.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want really easy with jquery.

```
<div class="button" id="article_button"><a href="#">
    <img src="../images/article.png"/>
    <p>Articles</p></a>
</div>



$('.button').on('hover', function(){
    $('#some_other_element').data('oldimg', $('#some_other_element').attr('src')).attr('src','other_image.jpg');
}, function(){
    $('#some_other_element').attr('src', $('#some_other_element').data('oldimg'));
});
```

Comment: This works, but when i move my mouse away, it still stays on the hover state image.

Comment: save the previous img and replace it back when hovering out. I will edit question